# JetBrains Upsource throwing unknown host error while connecting GCP cloud source repositories URL | SSH connection

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, ssh, upsource, jetbrains-hub

I'm trying to connect to google cloud Cloud source repositories to Jet Brains upsource in windows.
I'm facing an unknown host error.

I followed the gcloud documentation below for ssh connection

[https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/authentication#:~:text=Cloud%20Source%20Repositories%20lets%20you,public%20key%20with%20Google%20Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/authentication#:%7E:text=Cloud%20Source%20Repositories%20lets%20you,public%20key%20with%20Google%20Cloud).

I have tried configuring the ssh_config also for pointing the keys in IdentityFile

```
Host repo1
  HostName source.developers.google.com
  Port 2022
  user test.b@gmail.com
  IdentityFile /Users/balusur/.ssh/key1
```

[image: VCS connection error]

Not sure what I'm missing.
Anyone, please advise me on this?

Answer (score 1):

"Unknown host" means the fingerprint of the remote server is not properly registered in `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\known_hosts`

Try first in command line a `ssh repo1`, just to check if it asks you to add it to `known_hosts`.
Then try again from JetBrain itself.

As noted by the [OP debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6814764/debugger) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67537242/jetbrains-upsource-throwing-unknown-host-error-while-connecting-gcp-cloud-source/67543417#comment119460757_67543417):

> Jetbrains Upsource might not support GCP cloud source Repo: [issue `UP-10376`](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/UP-10376).

Also [`UP-9164`](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/UP-9164):

> According to the documentation page, it is possible to generate static credentials for accessing the repo without using the SDK, which means we don't have to do anything special to support them.

Comment: Thanks, @VonC. I checked the Known_hosts I able to see the entry for the same. I tried cloning using git clone ssh, it working as expected but the same is not with the JetBrains Up-source. Any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: @Debugger Is JetBrains Upsource launched with the same user account locally on your computer?

Comment: Yes both Git and Upsource started with the same account.

Comment: I hope it's not related to GCP accounts right?  Because the GCP account is different from the Upsource machine locally

Comment: @Debugger  Can you add to your environment, before launching Jetbrains Upsource, ```export GIT_SSH='ssh -tv'`? That way, we will see in JetBrains logs where it is looking for its keys.

Comment: Seems Jetbrains Upsource not supported GCP cloud source Repo https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/UP-10376

Comment: @Debugger Good catch. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.